# Docker: new parameters for attached container

Tags: docker

I run a container with some parameters in interactive mode.

```
docker run -i -t --name mycontainer myimage prm1 prm2
```

ENTERYPOINT is my application which uses parameters.

After the session was finished I'd like to start a new one with new parameters.

```
docker start mycontainer
docker attach mycontainer
```

How can I pass new parameters into the new session?

PS: Is it an appropriate scenario for interactive docker-application? Or I should create a new container for each new session?

Comment: Note to moderators: docker questions are 100% on topic on Stack Overflow. You will find thousands of similar questions regarding container and Dockerfile right here, on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It is best if you leave your [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint) to the default (`sh -c` or `my_application`), and use [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd) instead for the command parameter

```
CMD prm1 prm2
```

That means, by default, a docker run will use prm1 prm2 by default, but you can override them easily by passing new parameter on the next docker run.

---

That approach (above) is based on running a new container, instead of restarting an "Exited" one.

That is the common practice, as persistent data should be kept in a volume ([docker volume create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)) that you (re-)mount onto the new container (`docker run -v`)

If you were to restart your container, and benefit from *different* parameters, then it depends on your application:

- if said app can read those parameters from environment variables, the new [`docker update`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/) command ([PR 15078](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15078), still open on [issue 22490](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22490)) does ***not*** yet update environment variables (only cpu and memory)
- if said app can read those from a property file, you could use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy to that container an updated version of said property file, with new properties in it.

Comment: Let me clarify. The application uses parameters but there are no parameters by default. So, I can easily pass any param when I create container. But it is not clear how to pass new params when I restart (start+attach) container.

Comment: @DmitryPetrov you don't need to restart: you just start (run) a new container)

Comment: @DmitryPetrov " there are no parameters by default." : that is because you are using ENTRYPOINT. If you were using CMD, there would be parameter by default.

Comment: Got it. I know that this is a common docker practice for long-run daemon application. I'm trying to keep my interactive (not daemon) container for a long time by restarting.

Comment: Creating a new container is waste of resources for interactive application. But it looks like the best option.

Comment: @DmitryPetrov with docker cp, you don't have to create a new container, you can simply copy new files to an *existing* container.